# Repetition of a sequence in a column

Tags: r

I want to repeat again and again the given(below) sequence to fill approx 5000 rows in R.

Time data set:

```
8.00.00 AM
9.00.00 AM
10.00.00 AM
11.00.00 AM
12.00.00 PM
1.00.00 PM
2.00.00 PM
3.00.00 PM
4.00.00 PM
5.00.00 PM
6.00.00 PM
7.00.00 PM
8.00.00 PM
9.00.00 PM
```

Comment: `rep(1:10, len=25)` works for integers, I wonder if it works for strings or times...

Comment: rep(t$CaptureTime[1:15],length.out=5110) I tried this but I am getting a blank row after every sequence.I don't know how to remove this all.

Comment: You show 14 above (am I counting correctly?), are there really 15 known or is your `1:15` inadvertently including a blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several reasons why you see blanks. I'll focus on two possibles: `NA`s, and literal blanks.

```r
srcvec <- c("8.00.00 AM", "9.00.00 AM", "10.00.00 AM", "11.00.00 AM", "12.00.00 PM", 
"1.00.00 PM", "2.00.00 PM", "3.00.00 PM", "4.00.00 PM", "5.00.00 PM", 
"6.00.00 PM", "7.00.00 PM", "8.00.00 PM", "9.00.00 PM", NA, ""
)
rep(srcvec, len=30)
#  [1] "8.00.00 AM"  "9.00.00 AM"  "10.00.00 AM" "11.00.00 AM" "12.00.00 PM" "1.00.00 PM" 
#  [7] "2.00.00 PM"  "3.00.00 PM"  "4.00.00 PM"  "5.00.00 PM"  "6.00.00 PM"  "7.00.00 PM" 
# [13] "8.00.00 PM"  "9.00.00 PM"  NA            ""            "8.00.00 AM"  "9.00.00 AM" 
# [19] "10.00.00 AM" "11.00.00 AM" "12.00.00 PM" "1.00.00 PM"  "2.00.00 PM"  "3.00.00 PM" 
# [25] "4.00.00 PM"  "5.00.00 PM"  "6.00.00 PM"  "7.00.00 PM"  "8.00.00 PM"  "9.00.00 PM"
```

To remove the `NA`s, we can simply use `na.omit`:

```r
rep(na.omit(srcvec), len=30)
#  [1] "8.00.00 AM"  "9.00.00 AM"  "10.00.00 AM" "11.00.00 AM" "12.00.00 PM" "1.00.00 PM" 
#  [7] "2.00.00 PM"  "3.00.00 PM"  "4.00.00 PM"  "5.00.00 PM"  "6.00.00 PM"  "7.00.00 PM" 
# [13] "8.00.00 PM"  "9.00.00 PM"  ""            "8.00.00 AM"  "9.00.00 AM"  "10.00.00 AM"
# [19] "11.00.00 AM" "12.00.00 PM" "1.00.00 PM"  "2.00.00 PM"  "3.00.00 PM"  "4.00.00 PM" 
# [25] "5.00.00 PM"  "6.00.00 PM"  "7.00.00 PM"  "8.00.00 PM"  "9.00.00 PM"  ""
```

To remove blanks as well, we can filter on `nzchar`, which returns true when strings continue 1 or more characters:

```r
rep(Filter(nzchar, na.omit(srcvec)), len=30)
#  [1] "8.00.00 AM"  "9.00.00 AM"  "10.00.00 AM" "11.00.00 AM" "12.00.00 PM" "1.00.00 PM" 
#  [7] "2.00.00 PM"  "3.00.00 PM"  "4.00.00 PM"  "5.00.00 PM"  "6.00.00 PM"  "7.00.00 PM" 
# [13] "8.00.00 PM"  "9.00.00 PM"  "8.00.00 AM"  "9.00.00 AM"  "10.00.00 AM" "11.00.00 AM"
# [19] "12.00.00 PM" "1.00.00 PM"  "2.00.00 PM"  "3.00.00 PM"  "4.00.00 PM"  "5.00.00 PM" 
# [25] "6.00.00 PM"  "7.00.00 PM"  "8.00.00 PM"  "9.00.00 PM"  "8.00.00 AM"  "9.00.00 AM"
```

If you have non-empty blanks (e.g., whitespace), you can use this:

```r
srcvec <- c(srcvec, "   ")
rep(Filter(function(a) !is.na(a) & nzchar(gsub("\\s", "", a)), srcvec), len=30)
#  [1] "8.00.00 AM"  "9.00.00 AM"  "10.00.00 AM" "11.00.00 AM" "12.00.00 PM" "1.00.00 PM" 
#  [7] "2.00.00 PM"  "3.00.00 PM"  "4.00.00 PM"  "5.00.00 PM"  "6.00.00 PM"  "7.00.00 PM" 
# [13] "8.00.00 PM"  "9.00.00 PM"  "8.00.00 AM"  "9.00.00 AM"  "10.00.00 AM" "11.00.00 AM"
# [19] "12.00.00 PM" "1.00.00 PM"  "2.00.00 PM"  "3.00.00 PM"  "4.00.00 PM"  "5.00.00 PM" 
# [25] "6.00.00 PM"  "7.00.00 PM"  "8.00.00 PM"  "9.00.00 PM"  "8.00.00 AM"  "9.00.00 AM"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Time = paste(c(8:12,1:9),".00.00",sep = "")
PM_AM <- paste(Time,rep(c("AM","PM"),c(4,10)))
n_rep <- 5000 %/% length(PM_AM)
n_remain <- 5000 %% length(PM_AM)
x <- rep(PM_AM,n_rep)
x <- c(x,PM_AM[1:n_remain])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my onetree package from github yikeshu0611 to deal with problem.

```
devtools::install_github("yikeshu0611/onetree")
library(onetree)

df=read_Text("
time PAM
8.00.00 AM
9.00.00 AM
10.00.00 AM
11.00.00 AM
12.00.00 PM
1.00.00 PM
2.00.00 PM
3.00.00 PM
4.00.00 PM
5.00.00 PM
6.00.00 PM
7.00.00 PM
8.00.00 PM
9.00.00 PM
")
nrow(df)
358 ≈ 5000/14
```

df is your original data. Then we add the repeted number 358 to df.

```
df$n=358
```

Finally, we use `flat_strech` to **strech** data by n

```
df2=flat_strech(data=df,strech="n")
nrow(df2)
5012
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a vector includes the data and then use matrix

```
x <- c("8.00.00 AM",
"9.00.00 AM",
"10.00.00 AM",
"11.00.00 AM",
"12.00.00 PM",
"1.00.00 PM",
"2.00.00 PM",
"3.00.00 PM",
"4.00.00 PM",
"5.00.00 PM",
"6.00.00 PM",
"7.00.00 PM",
"8.00.00 PM",
"9.00.00 PM")

output <- matrix(x,5000)
```

Comment: great!...Simply great, this is what I was looking for , just 1 line code. Thanks!